# EF CF how to create one table that has three foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework

I have in my model Student that have a collection of all his subjects and every subject have collection of Educational matches.

```
public class Subject
{
     public int SubjectID { get; set; }
     public string SubjectName {get; set; }
     public ICollection<Student> { get; set; }
}

public class EducationalMatches
{
     public int EducationalMatchesID { get; set; }
     public int Number { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
     public int StudentID { get; set; }
     public Icollection<AllStudentSubjects> AllStudentSubjects{ get; set; }
}


public class AllStudentSubject
{
     public int AllStudentSubjectID { get; set; }
     public Subject Subject { get; set; }
     public ICollection<EducationalMatches> Educations { get; set; }
}
```

I'm expecting that in DB a table that looks like that will appear:

```
tableID
StudentID
SubjectID
EducationMatchesID
```

but no such table appears.
anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Having a model is not enough, you need to override [OnModelCreating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method (it is empty by default). Plus EF wants to have 'reverse' property, for example, if Student has a collection of Subjects, Subject should have a collection of Students (for many-to-many relationship)

In your case for AllStudentSubject it should be like this (did not test)

`protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<AllStudentSubject>()
    .HasKey(a => a.AllStudentSubjectID ) //Primary key, I prefer [Key] attribute, but this also works
    .HasRequired(a => a.Student) //Property in AllStudentSubject
    .WithMany(s => s.AllStudentSubjects) // Collection property in Student class
    .HasForeignKey(a => a.StudentId)//Second property in AllStudentSubject
//For Student, you do not have to write this all again, just the primary key
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
    .HasKey(a => a.StudentId ) //I like to move 'simple' declarations like this to the top
}`

For other two entities you have to do the same.
Here`s a great [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-1-introduction-and-basic-concepts) with all concepts explained

Comment: Is it possible to do it just with the relationship without using the "OnModelCreate" ?

Comment: You can use [DataAnnotations](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/dataannotation-in-code-first.aspx).